# Refinamento de Busca em Search View do Android

Tags: android, layout, filtro

Pessoal sou novo no mundo android vocês poderiam me ajudar indicando qual a forma de incluir estes filtros de refinamento de busca e de ordenação do texto que é digitado na searchview igual ao é apresentado no aplicativo do Walmart? A tela de refinamento não parece ser um Activity pois é possível visualizar a tela anterior logo abaixo dela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.